# Integrating Coral Admin Template with Durandal

Tags: durandal

I am trying to integrate Coral Admin Template with Durandal. Need help for integration. Please let me know if anybody had done it before. Your help is much appreciated.

Template link: http://www.mosaicpro.biz/item/coral-app-website-startup-kit-18.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, it just extends on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and throws a bit of custom JavaScript in there. Which particular aspects of integration are you struggling with?

Comment: George i have created a another thread where code is posted, please take a look

Comment: Hi George, please refer to following post, your help is appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447436/div-content-not-showing-when-html-code-moved-to-shell-html/23480942?iemail=1&noredirect=1#23480942